# I am trying to create session id using openTok android using java server sdk. I got the null pointer exception in session id

Tags: java, android, session, opentok

//create session

```
    OpenTok opentok = new OpenTok(45755142, "43a5a8def45fe62bcd5778c5ef6e2686237");
    SessionProperties sessionProperties=new SessionProperties.Builder()
            .mediaMode(MediaMode.ROUTED)
            .build();
    try {
        Session sample=opentok.createSession(sessionProperties);
        String sessionID=sample.getSessionId();
        Log.d(LOGTAG,sessionID);

    } catch (OpenTokException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.v("BUND",session.getSessionId());
```

my dependency files are:

```
compile 'com.opentok.android:accelerator-pack:+'
compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.8.+'
compile 'com.tokbox:opentok-server-sdk:2.3.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.1'
```

compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'